# Geomesa on Databricks - library installation fails

Tags: azure-databricks, geomesa

I would like to install the Geomesa library on Databricks, but choosing any geomesa library goes automatically to "failed". I have tried all of the available versions. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what databricks runtime is used? what message do you see when you click on the library instance

Comment: the runtime is 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12) and the error message: Library resolution failed. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa_2.12 download failed.

Comment: You should be using a different artifactID.  See https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa#spark-runtimes for an example.

Comment: Unfortunately this library (geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.12) is giving me the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, not a solution for the failure is to download the JAR from [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.geomesa/geomesa-tools) then upload it to dbfs (or upload it directly to the install wizard) then install it.

[image]